# Can't import 'mice' package in R on MacOS Mojave

Tags: r, import, r-mice

Can install 'mice' package in R but I can't import it. Same error keeps occurring after reinstallation of R and mice package. R version : 3.5.1

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in readRDS(mapfile):
unknown input format
```

Comment: you have dependency problems. You have always to tell also which version of R you are using.

Comment: R version is 3.5.1. mice package is not compatible with Mojave or newest R?

Comment: Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your post, and show us the code that produces the error.

Comment: also an important info is which OS you are using (windows, linux - which?, OSX). No, what I mean is some of your package dependencies is creating problems. R-3.5.1 is very new.

Answer (score -1):

Often if I encounter such problems, I check, what is package address in github.
Because often github accounts contain the most recent bug-fixed versions by the author.

```
# If not installed, do as preparation:
# install.packages("devtools")

devtools::install_github("stefvanbuuren/mice")
```

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.